# When should i reindex Design Config Grid?

Tags: magento2, reindex

There are different types of magento indexers as mentioned in

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Whats is use of **Design Config Grid** Indexer? and when does it get invalidate?

Answer (score 1):

**Design Config Grid Invalid time:**

1. ***When anyone Create a new store, store view, Website at Magento.***
2. ***Anyone deletes any store, store view, Website at Magento.***

*Then Design Config Grid indexer will be invalid*

Magento will indexer invalid function all on `aroundSave,afterDelete` plugin of `Magento\Store\Model\Website`,`Magento\Store\Model\Group`,`Magento\Store\Model\Website`

*After this two event on you need indexing over Design Config Grid.*

Comment: Is reindexing required after i update any layout file?

Comment: No, there is no need to do indexing after any change at layout.